# Universe with ZERO Fundamental Forces

Tags: forces, universe

Warning: I am not a physicist so please excuse my naivety!

As you all know, physicists think that there exist four fundamental forces.

Would a universe with zero fundamental forces be possible, at least in principle? Would elementary particles be able to exist in such a universe? On a larger scale, what would such a universe look like?

Answer (score 3):

"Forces" are in fact interactions particles (gauge bosons) as photons (electromagbetic force), gluons (strong interaction), Z and W bosons (weak interaction).

So no force means, at least, no photon, no gluon, no Z and W bosons.

This means too that matter particles like electrons, quarks, neutrinos, will not interact no more between them, so they would behave like unobservable ghosts.

But, in some sense, which is not observable does not exists.
So, no more matter too.

So, it seems that it will be an empty flat universe.

Comment: Yep basically nothing will "exist", there is no strong force, so atoms do not exist. No weak force so nuclear reactions cannot exist, no electromagnetic, so again atoms cannot exist nor can light "work". There is no gravity so the universe doesn't exist as it never coalesced together from small density perturbations